# Export to CSV file delimiter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I am facing problem with exporting csv. Problems are: 1) I have to export a html table to csv file . Can i change the delimiter of csv file to something else like semicolon. If I have values in the table under the same column separated by comma, in the csv sheet it is showing in a different column. For eg in the code:"Apple,Banana,Mango" I want it in the same column.
2) My code is not working for IE and it is only working for mozilla 3) Also I wanted the user to save the csv file. Now it is getting automatically saved. Please find my code . Can any body help with any of the issue.

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/anbffh8p/4/

CodeHTML:

```
      <div><a href="#" class="export">Export Table data into Excel</a></div>
```

Code JS:

```
    function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
alert('inside');

 var csvData = [];
 var tmpArr = [];

           csvData.push("mechanical" + "," + "in process" + "," + "M00001" + "," + "A" + "," + "Test" + "," + "Xyz" + "," + "Apple,Banana,Mango");

            csvData.push(tmpArr.join('\n')); 
            // printObject(tmpArr);

        alert('before this');
            var output = csvData.join('\n');
         csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(output);

    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'

    });

    alert('done');
}


$(".export").on('click', function (event) {
    // CSV
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this,['export.csv']);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In Summary: If you can, use server-side code, not javascript to send a csv file to the user.

---

> I have to export an html table to csv file.

Do you have any server side code?  What is generating the table in the first place?   php/C#-asp-net-mvc?  This will be much easier on the server.

You're essentially creating a `url` with all the data on - urls have a maximum length (depending on browser but generally <2000 chars) so will only be of use for small amounts of data.

> Can I change the delimiter of csv file to something else like semicolon.

Yes.  Did you not write the code yourself?

```
 csvData.push("mechanical" + "," + "in process" + "," + "M00001" + "," + "A" + "," + "Test" + "," + "Xyz" + "," + "Apple,Banana,Mango");
```

the simplest change (but I'd normally use a var for the separator) :

```
csvData.push("mechanical" + ";" + "in process" + ";" + "M00001" + ";" + "A" + ";" + "Test" + ";" + "Xyz" + ";" + "Apple,Banana,Mango");
```

> If I have values in the table under the same column separated by comma, in the csv sheet it is showing in a different column.

This is a misunderstanding of how CSV files work.  They are not just `line.split("'")`.

Basically, put double quotes around your cell, eg:

```
Test,Xyz,"Apple,Banana,Mango"
```

to get quotes, use double-double-quotes, eg:

```
Test,"in ""quotes""",xyz
```

> My code is not working for IE and it is only working for mozilla 
>   [and chrome]

You use a url feature to specify the download:  "data:application/csv" (rather than "href:...")  - this will be handled by different browsers differently.

> it is getting automatically saved

A browser feature / end-user specific option.   FF/GC generally auto-save to downloads rather than prompt for save.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs. My doubt is still not very clear. yes I am uploading values to the table from server. But that is not a problem here. My problem is I need to make the csv dependent on any other delimiter than comma so that it doesnt affect my data.

Comment: For the code I tried this: csvData.push("mechanical" + ";" + "in process" + ";" + "M00001" + ";" + "A" + ";" + "Test" + ";" + "Xyz" + ";" + "Apple,Banana,Mango");  but the result is coming as:::::::mechanical;in process;M00001;A;Test;Xyz in one row. Apple in 2nd row. Banana in third and Mango in fourth. This is because csv depends on comma .

Comment: Just add quotes around the data, replace any quotes in the data with 2 quotes. See here, scroll down to 'basic rules and format' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: "many implementations of CSV import/export tools allow other separators to be used" - csv doesn't have to be a comma - it's the tool that opens it that determines.   In this case Excel sees your other commas in the data and there's only one line so can't make a guess that you actually wanted ";".  If you save the file then *import* there's an option to specify a different delimiter.  But keep with comma and quotes, it's simpler.

Comment: Hi , thanks a lot for replying. I am still not able to do so by adding double quotes aswell. Can you look  into the fiddle code:https://jsfiddle.net/anbffh8p/4/ .. You can try making changes. It doesnot work. Also I want user to decide on the file save name and destination. Can it be done using js. For now it is automatically getting saved.

Comment: This update puts Apple,Banana,Mango in a single cell.  https://jsfiddle.net/anbffh8p/8/ Tested with FF.  FF prompts me to save as it's a *user specific option* (but not where as that's a FF option).  You'll generally be better using server-side as you'll have more control.